# .load call inside setInterval() only works once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I can't get the interval to refresh more than once.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#testButton').load('test', function (response, status, xhr) {

        if (status == "error") {
            document.write("helloworld");
        }
        else {
            $('#testButton').replaceWith(response);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

The test function I'm calling in `.load` is this (I'm just getting current time):

```
public ActionResult test()
{
    DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
    currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    String timeStr = currentTime.ToString();

    return Content(timeStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
 $('#testButton').replaceWith(response);
```

In successful return of the value you replace the element, so it no longer exist in future executions of the function (and actually function executes but generates an error). replace it with:

```
$('#testButton').html(response);
```

to change its content, and not just replace element itself with the return value of ajax.